# refresh the fragment when getting back from an activity or pressing back

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I was trying to refresh the fragment when pressing back from an activity, I tried using onResume() and onStop() and it worked but... another issue comes. using onResume() and onStop() inside the fragment is making the fragment refresh too many times that the app is crashing and I really don't know what I am doing wrong, if you can please help me with this issue

my onResume() function

```
   override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        //shoudRefreshOnResume is a global var
        if (shouldRefreshOnResume) {
            val ft: FragmentTransaction = parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            ft.detach(this).attach(this).commit()
        }
    }
```

my onStop() function

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    shouldRefreshOnResume = true
}
```

my onCreateView() function

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    val foodButton = root.findViewById<Button>(R.id.mainFoodButton)
    val recentlyViewed = root.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.recently_viewedView)

    foodButton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(activity, CategoriesActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    //createRecentlyViewedButton() is a function
    createRecentlyViewedButton(recentlyViewed)

    return root
}
```

Comment: Please provide an errorlog, without it we can only guess what your error might be

Comment: Instead of detaching and attaching in onResume, try calling only createRecentlyViewedButton(recentlyViewed) method there. You can remove that call from the onCreateView(). It's not a good practice to "refresh" the fragment the way you're doing.

Comment: @TiagoOrnelas I replaced the detaching and attaching from onResume() and changed it to calling the function, and it worked thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by replacing onStop() function to onPause() since the activity is not getting destroyed and it no longer loop the createRecentlyViewedButton() function hope this help somebody

here are the changes I made though

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    shouldRefreshOnResume = true
}
```

and

```
   override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        //shoudRefreshOnResume is a global var
        if (shouldRefreshOnResume) {
        val recentlyViewed = activity?.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.recently_viewedView)
        createRecentlyViewedButton(recentlyViewed!!)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate the follow up MQ. Welcome to SO. Creds to you.

Comment: @portsample Thank you

Comment: More creds for you if you resolve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67207257/